# Problems with fixed property in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am adding a new feature to my portfolio where the header sticks to the top, aka the property changes to fixed when it reaches certain scrollY value range, this is working but unfortunately the `position:fixed`

Before scrolling, with position set to it's initial default value
[image]

After scrolling down, the header gets a fixed property but whitespace kicks in to the far right side of the window. 
[image]

How do I fix this problem?
Here is html code:

```
<div class="fluid-container row header header-f">
    <div class="col-md-4 sitename">
      <h1 class="site_name center">buoyantair</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 sitemenu">
      <div class="menu center">
        <a class="btn" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="btn" href="#">About</a>
        <a class="btn" href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS code:
.

```
header-f {
    max-height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    animation: slide-in .5s;
}
.header {
    background: linear-gradient(15deg, #5DCC90 70%, #ADD962);
    color: #214732;
    min-height: 10vh;
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

You can watch this live here https://buoyantair.github.io/

Comment: Set the width for the element to `100%`

Comment: You have to provide some code of your project.

Comment: width:100% and right:0px;

Comment: I just added `margin: 0;` to `<div class="fluid-container row header  header-f">` and worked

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: @Quentin I am sorry, I forgot about the code, I was in a hurry. I'll try to post code the next time!

Comment: row class in your header is adding margin-right: -15px and margin-left: -15px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `left:0; right:0;` to the styling of the header should ensure that it always sticks to both sides of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

well i tried to follow bootstrap style

put a row inside container and remove 'row' class from header .. see comments below

```
<div class="fluid-container header"> <!--remove row class -->
<div class="row"> <!-- add row here -->
<div class="col-md-4 sitename">
  <h1 class="site_name center">buoyantair</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 sitemenu">
  <div class="menu center">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="btn" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="btn" href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `right: 0` to your `.header-f`

```
.header-f {
    max-height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    animation: slide-in .5s;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it By adding Row after Container-fluid.

as row contains **margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;**

```
<div class="fluid-container header     ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 sitename">
          <h1 class="site_name center">buoyantair</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 sitemenu">
          <div class="menu center">
            <a class="btn" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="btn" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="btn" href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Hope It Helps